# Excel/VBA changing date when there are changes to the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

is it possible in Excel to insert today's date into a Workbook/sheet only when the data inside the sheet is changed.

So what I mean by this is that there is a workbook with several sheets and if somebody makes changes to this sheets I want to have my date updated that is in a specific cell. For better understanding lets just say that this cell is C5 of the first worksheet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, use `Worksheet_Change` event, and then add `Range("C5").Value = Date`

Comment: yes this does actualy work but the worksheet_change event is triggerd when the date changes to a new date,then it is triggered again and again.

Is there a way to keep c5 out of this loop?
Meaning c5 is the only cell not to be monitored by this worksheet_change event?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' check that the cell changed is not "C5"
If Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("C5").Value = Date
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```